# How to connect a motorola RVA50UL with MR350?

Tags: uhf, frequency, tone-squelch

Currently I use a Motorola [MR30R](https://www.motorolasolutions.com/content/dam/msi/docs/products/two-way-radios/consumer/mr350-mx-uy-pa-us.pdf) radio in the frequency 20 (462,6750 Mhz) with Interference Eliminator Code 59. I also have a Motorola [RVA50UL](https://www.motorolasolutions.com/content/dam/msi/docs/en-xl/products/two-way-radios-business/portable-radios/on-site-small-business/rva50/RVA50_User_Guide.pdf), according to the manual, the frequency will be available at channel 3, but I am not able to set the interference eliminator code. the manual does not define that.

I am misreading the manual of the RVA50UL?

Comment: Is this in relation to HAM/Amateur Radio? The reason I am asking is because 462.675 MHz would be outside the allocated bands... it seems to be about GMRS/FRS radio service (GMRS assigned channel 20 -- US based).

Comment: Did you read page 33 of the RVA50UL manual? On this page, it's explained how to program the CTCSS tone.